# Python - Pandas - Set New DataFrame from SubSelect Mask Not Index Error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to set a new dataFrame based on the user values being set for the date variables below. the raw data date column (`Date`) comes into pandas in the following format `7/5/17`. Following what I assume are best practices, I convert the field into `datetime` format which produces an array with the `yyyy-mm-dd` format, `'2017-12-01', '2017-12-02', '2017-12-03', '2017-12-04','2017-12-05',`. From here I am trying to subselect my dataFrame with a `date_range` within my start and end date and then only show the columns being selected with variables `X` and `y`. However, I produce `raise KeyError('{mask} not in index'.format(mask=objarr[mask]))` at the subselect line. What value in my code could be throwing that error? Is it due to the `datetime` formatting?

```
# date column and conversion to datetime64[ns]
dateColumn = pd.to_datetime(rawData['Date'])

# date start
dateStart = '12/1/17'

# date end
dateEnd = '2/28/18'

# date range
dateRange = pd.date_range(dateStart, dateEnd)


# dependent variable
y = 'Leads'

# independent variable(s)
X = 'Clicks'
```

**Sub-select x and y columns for Date rows between 12/1/17 and 2/28/18:**

```
print(rawData[rawData[dateColumn].isin(dateRange)][X,y])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indexing with the column instead of the column name:

```
print(rawData[dateColumn.isin(dateRange)][[X,y]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it makes sense, but it looks like the column selection is throwing an error when there is greater than one column selected `[X,y]`. Error returned is `KeyError: ('Leads', 'Clicks')`  `/Users/test/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance) try: return self._engine.get_loc(key) except KeyError:`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check that part, probably you should pass an array there. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Ahh that fixed it. Thank you!